# Python - Compare user input with class object instance

Tags: python, class, input, compare

I'm creating a program, where people will guess the identity of someone, based on user input and predefined values.

`class myPeople(object):`

```
`def __init__(self, name, age, gender):`
`self.name = name`
`self.age = age`
`self.gender = gender`
```

`name=input("What is your name?\n")`

`age=input("What is your age?\n")`

`gender=input("What is your gender?\n")`

`smith = myPeople(name="smith", age="104", gender="female")`

`john = myPeople(name="john", age="14", gender="male")`

I would like to compare the user input with values that are preassigned to "smith" and "john". I thought that I could do:

`if smith.myPeople is True:`

```
   `print("You are Mr. Smith")`
```

`elif john.myPeople is True:`

```
   `print("You are Mr. John")`
```

I'm getting the error AttributeError: type object 'myPeople' has no attribute 'smith'

Also, I'm not sure, if the statement "is True" will work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you expect `smith.myPeople` to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize your class](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) by adding a [comparison method, in this case `__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).  Then you can just check to see if class instances are equal.

```
class myPeople(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.name == other.name and
                self.age == other.age and
                self.gender == other.gender)

smith = myPeople(name="smith", age="104", gender="female")
john = myPeople(name="john", age="14", gender="male")

>>> smith == john
False
>>> smith == smith
True
>>> john == smith
False
>>> john == john
True
>>>
```

Use the user's responses to create another instance then compare.

```
>>> name = 'smith'
>>> age = '104'
>>> gender = 'female'
>>> foo = myPeople(name = name, age = age, gender = gender)
>>> foo == smith
True
>>> foo == john
False
>>>
```